# How to add switch control to mvc application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, uiswitch

I need to add switch control to my web application.
I'm trying to use [Kendo Switch](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/hybrid/switch/switch) control.
I want to bind my switch to a model property.
I do that with a following way:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Guest Mode:")
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.SomeProperty, new {@id = "switch"})
    </label>
</div>
<script>
    var switchInstance = $("#switch").kendoMobileSwitch();
</script>
```

I tried many ways but can not render so simply control properly (see my screenshot).[image]

Also I tried to use only razor syntax but it rendered only a checkbox.
What is my problem and how to fix it?
Thanks for advance!

Comment: This is probably because `CheckBoxFor()` generates 2 elements (`<input type="checkbox" ... />` and `<input type="hidden" .... />` so the css selectors associated with you plugin do not work. Try initially by creating a manual checkbox `<input type="checkbox" id="switch" />` and if that generates the correct view, show the appropriate html and css so it can be corrected

Comment: @StephenMuecke Actuall no. It has rendered the same "styled" switch.

Comment: Then are you sure you have included the relevant scripts? Are you getting any errors in the browser console?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have a error: `Failed to load resource:net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` in `http://localhos/.../browserLink` but it was displayed earlier. No more errors during click that control.

Comment: @StephenMuecke specify, control works properly. I get correct value from model in controller.

Answer (score 0):

I've done it like that. The goal is to switch on/off 'disabled' attribute for some text fields. In my case this way works just fine. I hope it's useful.
In the label tag 'for' is the binding with model property method. Checkbox is bound with the model by Html helper.

```
<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Enabled, new { @class = "custom-control-input" })
             <label class="custom-control-label" for="Enabled">Disable</label>
        </div>
```

and next is jQuery script:

```
@section Scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(DOM_Load);

    function DOM_Load(e) {
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
            container: "body"
        });

        $("div.custom-switch").children("input").on("change", EnabledToggle_Change);
    }

    function EnabledToggle_Change(e) {
        var inputs = $("div.container-fluid").find("input[type!='checkbox']");
        var textareas = $("div.container-fluid").find("textarea");
        var switchLabel = $("div.custom-switch").children(".custom-control-label");

        switchLabel.text(switchLabel.text() == 'Disable' ? 'Enable' : 'Disable');
        inputs.prop('disabled', (i, v) => !v);
        textareas.prop('disabled', (i, v) => !v);
    }
</script>
```

}